# Why are there 3 identical R.java files in MyTracks?

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm studying the MyTracks code. I find that gen/com/google/android/apps/mytracks/lib/R.java, gen/com/google/android/gms/R.java, and gen/com/google/android/maps/mytracks/R.java are identical except for their package statements. The corresponding Manifest.java files are identical too except for their package statements. I did an experiment: In strings.xml I created a new string "zzz_test" with value "Why are there 3 R.java files?", and sure enough zzz_test showed up in all three R.java files. Why all the duplication?

Comment: Possibly they could all be library projects all referencing the same library project

Comment: Thanx @JRowan your comment led me in the right direction